# Remove empty paragrapf and change h3 element css

Tags: html, css

I have some blog on a `wordpress` webpage. These blogs can be added from dashboard. The problem is that the new blogs generates some `html` elements that mess up the design.

This is the hml that is generated:

```
<div class="loop-entry-excerpt entry clr" style="position: absolute;">
    <p></p>
    <h3>Creating a Culture of Innovation</h3>
      Last week, I had the opportunity...
   <p></p>
   <div class="button_Read_More text-right">
       <a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/tips-from-googleplex/"><span id="readMore_button" class="blog_readmore">Read more</span></a>
        </div>
     </div>
```

The problem is with the two paragraphs`<p></p>` and that the text is in a `h3` element. The text should be in a `<p>`

It should be:

```
<div class="loop-entry-excerpt entry clr" style="position: absolute;">

    <p>Creating a Culture of Innovation
      Last week, I had the opportunity...</p>

   <div class="button_Read_More text-right">
       <a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/tips-from-googleplex/"><span id="readMore_button" class="blog_readmore">Read more</span></a>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Can you please advise how can I resolve this by css? Can I do this with pure css? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `p:empty` to remove empty `p` elements. But I don't think you can replace `p` for a `h3` with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I do this with pure css?

I doubt that, but below jQuery may help

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('h3').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<p>'+$(this).text()+'<p>');
  });
  $('p').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).text().length){
    $(this).remove();
  }
  });

});
});
```

See the fiddle [[ **here** ]](https://jsfiddle.net/s76zvr76/).